# Getting a LUA script to round off at two decimals?

Tags: lua, display

This is about a .LUA script and since I'm "fiddling" with game physics (mainly the car itself in Asseto Corsa) and now a non-properly-working dash: I was getting into the .LUA scripts.
And its hard.....never done anything like it but it IS interesting and I want to fix my problem and some more when I'm done with that. See what is possible, right?

Anyway, there is a mod for a car and that one makes the digital dash in the car way nicer.
When you set your brake balance for instance, like in real life, the screen goes white and shows "53,5" in big font for a second.
It stays in the display in a smaller version too.

Now one setting is "Brake Migration" or BMIG.
That is no standard feature of the game like BB is and when you add up- or down, it makes a huge number, falling out of the screen: 0,999877395048373636 lets say.

So I looked up the line:

```
    ui.beginScale()
    drawText{
        string = BMIG+1,
        fontSize = 30,
        xPos = 250,
        yPos = 500,
        xAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
        yAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
        margin = vec2(400, 550),
        color = rgbm(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)
    }
    ui.endScale(2)

    ui.popDWriteFont()
end
```

On this site I found a proper set of lines, pasted that in there and it didn't work for me.
So I thought brake balance is one decimal, lets try that!
It said:

```
    ui.beginScale()
    drawText{
        string = string.format("%.1f", car.brakeBias*100),
        fontSize = 200,
        xPos = 10,
        yPos = 450,
        xAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
        yAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
        margin = vec2(1000, 550),
        color = rgbm(0, 0, 0, 1)
    }
    ui.endScale(2)
```

I stole the line, made it this:

```
ui.beginScale()
drawText{
    string = string.format("%.1f", car.BMIG+1*100),
    fontSize = 30,
    xPos = 250,
    yPos = 500,
    xAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
    yAlign = ui.Alignment.Center,
    margin = vec2(400, 550),
    color = rgbm(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1)
}
ui.endScale(2)
```

Nope! Screen does turn into the background, but no numbers are displayed anymore. Neither do the smaller numbers change.
I tried every configuration that "looked good to me" and then some: can't get it to work.

If anyone with a bit of knowledge on this stuff would give me a few hints and tricks, that would be awesome!
Thanks in advance, kind regards.

Comment: What is the reason why `BMIG+1` has become `car.BMIG+1*100`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
That was a mistake: that was copied out of a file I was messing around with to get it working. I did leave the "car." out at first try though.